# why android studio 2 do not display layout in design

Tags: android, android-studio

how can I display layouts in design view of android studio 2.

[image]

Comment: may be some error in xml that is only reason, design not visible ........

Comment: go to text next to design.. and open preview..

Comment: try to change android rendering version  from **N => 23,21** etc and check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the upper right corner of your rendering view and change it from "N".

[image]

You can have the design preview by selecting the **Text** tab in the bottom left side and when it opens with Text view you'll have a **Preview** button at the right side. Open it to see the run time changes in layouts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now you have selected **N** it change to lower version from top right corner of designview. see the red marked area

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the upper right of your rendering view and change from "N".  That is a preview API level and usually doesn't render properly in the Design View.

Any time you update the SDK and install a preview version, you can pretty much count on your design view not working right until you render it in an actually released version of the Android SDK.